# Propetries of ideals and zero sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ideals, zariski-topology

Why we obtain $I(X_1 \cup X_2) = I(X_1) \cap I(X_2)$ and $Z(J_1 \cup J_2)= Z(J_1) \cap Z(J_2)$?

- for a subset $X⊆\mathbb{A}^n,$ $I(X)$ is the ideal of $f∈k[x_1,⋯,x_n]$ with $f|X=0$ and
- for a subset $J⊆k[x_1,⋯,x_n],$ $Z(J)$ is the closed subset of $\mathbb{A}^n$ defined by $∩_{f∈J}Z(f).$

I would like to have example of it.

For example $X_1 = \{(1:0:0)\}$ is point. $X_2 =\{(x-y)\}$ is line.

Is it correct $X_1 \cup X_2 = \{(x-y)\}$ or no?
How can I write: $I(X_1 \cup X_2)$ and $I(X_1) \cap I(X_2)$?
And how we can get example $Z(J_1 \cup J_2)= Z(J_1) \cap Z(J_2)$?

Comment: 1) $X_1\cup X_2=X_2\iff X_1\subset X_2.$ 2) Write down (in your post) the definitions of the maps $X\mapsto I(X)$ and $J\mapsto Z(J)$ and apply them.

Comment: {subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$} $\rightarrow $ {ideals of $k[x_1, \cdots x_n ]$} 
and {subsets of $k[x_1, \cdots , x_n]$} $\rightarrow $ {closed subsets of $\mathbb{A}^n$} , where for a subset $X \subseteq \mathbb{A}^n$, $I(X)$ is the ideal of $f \in k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$ with $f|X = 0$ and for a subset $J \subseteq k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$, Z(J) is the closed subset of$\mathbb{A}^n$ defined by $\cap _{f \in J} Z(f)$. Is it correct @AnneBauval? Could you explain this problem? please and thank you!

Answer (score 0):

$$f|(X_1\cup X_2)=0\iff f|X_1=0\text{ and }f|X_2=0.$$$$\cap_{f\in J_1\cup J_2}Z(f)=\bigcap_{f\in J_1}Z(f)\cap\bigcap_{f\in J_2}Z(f).$$

Comment: Thank you! But could  you please write the exact example (point and line)? I try to understand and learn it on this example. Please

Comment: I would like to, but I don't understand your notation for $X_2.$ What is $\{(x-y)\}$? is it a subset of $\mathbb A^n$? for which $n$, and which subset?

Comment: It is line in $\mathbb{A}^2$. But when you have other and correct example for these properties I woud like to consider it and learn. @Anne Bauval

Comment: Is it the line $\{(x;y)\in\mathbb A^2\mid x-y=0\},$ or what? And I find it strange to take a union of $X_1\subset\mathbb A^3$ with $X_2\subset\mathbb A^2.$ That said, I have no idea of example which would be more helpful than the general formulas above: this is not algebra, only elementary set-theory.

Comment: Maybe I take bad example for $I(X_1 \cup X_2) = I(X_1) \cap I(X_2)$ and $Z(J_1 \cup J_2)= Z(J_1) \cap Z(J_2)$.  I would like to take  line $\{(x;y)\in \mathbb{A}^2 ∣ x−y=0\}$ and point for these equation...  and I have no idea what other example could be given that would be good for these properties $I(X_1 \cup X_2) = I(X_1) \cap I(X_2)$ and $Z(J_1 \cup J_2)= Z(J_1) \cap Z(J_2)$ @Anne Bauval

Comment: Excuse me Artur but I can't see how any example could enlighten these 2 very elementary equalities. Which part of my 2 lines answer don't you understand?